# UML page connector

Tags: uml

Does anybody know if there is a symbol for page connector in UML's activity diagrams?

Common flowcharts have a symbol to represent that a process continues on another page such as:

[image: flowchart off page connector symbol]

This symbol sometimes has a text in it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UML Interaction Overview diagrams for this purpose. They let you use interactions defined elsewhere as elements.

Answer (score 1):

I draw activity diagrams in Visio, and use the flowchart page connector with text.  The page connectors have labels (and sometimes comments) describing where they are going to or coming from.

This may not be strict UML, but it works.